# Having trouble adding mouseover tooltips to icons with Bootstrap/Less

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2013, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

So I am using VS 2013 with Bootstrap (and LESS), and I'm trying to get particular icons in the table to have a tooltip effect upon mouseover. I was wondering if it's possible to add the mouseover effect to the particular icon in icons.less? Particularly, I'm using Font Awesome icons.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far? (see also [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: Well, I'm new to Visual Studio, so everything I've tried so far has been in the actual div where the icons are located, but it hasn't worked. I see the icons.less file has a bunch of different ".@{fa-css-prefix}-glass:before { content: @fa-var-glass; }" lines. I wasn't sure if I could add a tooltip function to the specific lines/icons, and I didn't want to risk messing anything up.